# Run SSIS Package from T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I noticed you can use the following stored procedures (in order) to schedule a SSIS package:

```
msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
msdb.dbo.sp_add_job ...
msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep ...
msdb.dbo.sp_update_job ...
msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule ...
msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver ...
```

(You can see an example by right clicking a scheduled job and selecting "Script Job as-> Create To".)

AND you can use sp_start_job to execute the job immediately, effectively running SSIS packages on demand.

**Question: does anyone know of any msdb.dbo.[...] stored procedures that simply allow you to run SSIS packages on the fly without using sp_cmdshell directly, or some easier approach?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't strictly need the `sp_add_category`, `sp_update_job` or `sp_add_jobschedule` calls.  We do an on-demand package execution in our app using SQL Agent with the following call sequence:

```
 - sp_add_job 
 - sp_add_jobstep
 - sp_add_jobserver 
 - sp_start_job
```

Getting the job status is a little tricky if you can't access the msdb..sysjobXXX tables, but our jobs start & run just fine.

**EDIT::** Other than xp_cmdshell, I'm not aware of another way to launch the the SSIS handlers from withinSQL Server.  Anyone with permissions on the server can start the dtexec or dtutil executables; then you can use batch files, job scheduler etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not really... you could try sp_OACreate but it's more complicated and may not do it.

Do you need to run them from SQL? They can be run from command line, .net app etc

Comment: We would rather execute it from SQL rather than provide the means to our web servers.  Our web servers are not in the same ms domain as the SQL servers (not even on the same network).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+ it is possible to use the following functions (found in the `SSISDB` database, not the `msdb` database) to create SSIS execution jobs, prime their parameters, and start their execution:

[[catalog].[create_execution]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-execution-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-2017)

[[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-set-execution-parameter-value-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-2017)

[[catalog].[start_execution]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-start-execution-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-2017)